# MySQL 8 update, set, case

Tags: mysql

I'm testing a multiple update  `SET col1 = col2 WHEN col1 != col2`

I don't understand, why it doesn't work. I see in output only info about `Row matched` and nothing about affected rows

```
UPDATE db.t1
    JOIN db.t2
    ON  t1.id = t2.id
    JOIN db.t3
    ON t2.id = t3.id
SET col1 = CASE
    WHEN col1 != col2
    THEN col1 = col2
    END
WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND t3.id = t2.id and t1.id = 2
```

Comment: You are aware that `col1 = col2` in `THEN col1 = col2 ...` is taken as a Boolean expression and therefore yields 1?

Answer (score 1):

Be caferul to this  ..  `THEN col1 = col2`   .. in this case teh code is evaluated  as logical  condition  (and the resul could be 0 or 1)  ..

if you want set col2 to col1 depending on case result then  you should use

```
UPDATE db.t1
JOIN db.t2 ON  t1.id = t2.id
JOIN db.t3  ON t2.id = t3.id
SET col1 = CASE
    WHEN col1 != col2
    THEN  col2
    END
WHERE t1.id = t2.id 
AND t3.id = t2.id 
AND t1.id = 2
```